# subsample from dataframe and saving output as rows of a matrix

Tags: r

I am new to R. I have to repeat some process several times. In each iteration, I have to take a sub-sample from a data-frame, and to save the output which already is an array as rows of a matrix.
To take sub-sample I am using

```
mysample <- mydata[sample(1:nrow(mydata), 200,replace=T),]
```

and to save output in 'finmat' matrix

```
finmat<- matrix(nrow=100, ncol=7)  # initialization with 100 iteration
```

in each iteration suppose looping index is `k`, 
`finmat[k,]<- rs`
where `rs` is vector of length 7.
help me to accomplish this task.

Comment: I think you are being very unspecific when you talk about data frames - a subsample of a data frame is a data frame (not an array), and a matrix is a simpler object so it won't work to save the subset as "rows of a matrix". Everything will be clear if you make a reproducible example by sharing a little sample input data (use `dput(droplevels(head(your_data)))` so all the structural information is preserved) and also show a little bit of what your desired output would look like. [See here for a nice tutorial on creating reproducible examples in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061).

Comment: A little confused -- you want to take samples of 200 rows apiece, but you also want to store each sample as a single row of the output matrix... If that's right, then how are the 200 rows reduced to a single one?

Comment: head(mydata)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   4    5    0   20
[2,]   2    2    1   29
[3,]   2    5    0   38
[4,]   4    5    0   28
[5,]   3    5    0   08
[6,]   2    4    1   25  suppose this is my data. using these columns, I calculate several values say v1, v2, v3, v4, v5. so at each iteration, I have to save these 5 values. and repeating this process after 100 time, I have to take mean of each five values. so what should I do??